# Odoo 9.0.1 Warning - Access Error

Tags: acl, odoo-9

I have installed Odoo 9.0.1 ,and it's work good,then i installed Project Management App .

Then i have added Project user as the image below :

[image]

after that i have created an issue and assign it to Mark (Project User),but Mark from his account can't access the project issues or tasks,it's only shows the Dashboard without all Project menu items:

[image]

So how to change the security permission so the project user not the manager can view specific things in Project Module .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to give the Rights for the  user for the particular task... 
    so you have to create 1 group suppose name is group1 and create 1 user suppose name is user1
    you can create group and user through the 2 way first is through the coding and second way is front end side.
    Create one folder name is Security,under this folder create one xml file name like security.xml.

```
create xml file for the security.

<openerp>
    <!-- Create user -->    
    <data>
        <record id="user1" model="res.users">
            <field name="name">user1</field>
            <field name="login">user1</field>
            <field name="password">user1</field>
        </record>
    </data>

    <!-- Create Group -->
    <data>
        <record id=”group_1“ model="res.groups”>
            <field name="name">group1</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
now you have to assign your user1 into the group1 through front end side.
```

you can also assign this user into the group1 through coding for that ...
 under group code.
    now you have to give the permission for the particular task or the module you can give also front end side and through csv file .
Create CSV file ....

```
Name must be ir.model.access.csv for the csv file.
this file also put under the security folder.
```

**id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink**
access_user1,task_user1,model_contact_contact,contact_advance.group_contact_all,1,1,0,0

you can also give the rights through the front end side also in the group edit mode.

```
now you can login as user1 and you can access your projects.
```

I hope this answer is helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you for your gently answer.I will try your solution and provide you with Feedback.

Comment: If this Answer is helpful for you then please Accept this Answer and provide Upvote ...Thank you